# Using checkboxes with ASP.NET and Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, input, checkbox, repeater

I have Javascript code that does this:

`var oObjchbox = document.getElementById("CheckBox_" + countyId);`

The countyId comes from an image map that is pre-made.

The checkboxes on the other hand are created by ASP.NET. My first try was to use an asp.repeater with asp:checkBox, but that did not do the trick since ASP.NET insists on creating own IDs. The other try was to use HTML INPUT without runat=server, but then the checkboxes did not survive a roundtrip.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I found a similar problem over here

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t301617-hijack-databoundliteralcontrol.html

but no one answered his question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is getting the ID from the Checkbox within a Repeater then this article might help, [Select All Checkboxes in a GridView](https://web.archive.org/web/20210316002334/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053106-1.aspx). It shows how to generate a Client Side select all feature on an ASP.Net Gridview.

The issue you are dealing with is not an uncommon one.  You want to access a control that is in a control that repeats layout (GridView, Repeater, DataList and the like) using JavaScript.

The thing to remember is that you can access the generated ClientId during the DataBound events (**RowDataBound**, **ItemDataBound**) which can then be used on the client side.

Then on the return trip as this is a standard control you should be able to find it.  However if you are using a Repeater then Updating data might require a bit more work as the control itself is more designed for read-only type displays.

If the problem is mapping each control to a predefined StateCode then in the ItemDataBound or RowDataBound(if you change from Repeater to Something else) events you could wire a call to a JavaScript method with 1 or 2 parameters depending on the need.  Either the currentCheckBoxId and the appropriate StateCode separately or already concatenated and use that as a lookup type feature.

Sorry for the two answers, but the question seemed a little vague as to what you were actually trying to do, maybe I just need another cup of coffee. Hope one of these ideas help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for solve this problem, it provide functionality to select elements by custom query, for example

$("[id*=CheckBox1") - return all elements where end of id is  CheckBox1.

$("[id^=CheckBox1") - return all elements where start of id is  CheckBox1.

and you can find by contains word and many other selectors.

For more information jquery.com, you will like it =)

Comment: Very interesting and useful jquery functions, but it will unfortunately not help me in a repeater where I can only set one ID that is common for all repeater items. ASP.NET will then add unique string to the ID. So I can not match the countyID with the generated asp.net ID. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to detect the selected Checkboxes on the server, why not create a hidden field and update client side by concatenating the country id with each click to create a delimited list such as usa;ca;nl?  Read that value on the postback, parse, and you have the countries that have been selected.

In your PageLoad issue the following:  RegisterHiddenField("txtCountryCodes","");